# watir-classic 3.7.0 click on unsupported tag

Tags: html, ruby, internet-explorer, automated-tests, watir

I'm trying to click on a  tag with watir classic 3.7.0 which is unsupported. Generally, it looks as though I can find the tag with a line such as:

```
browser.td(:id, 'Proceed').element(:tag_name => 'FONT')
```

and

```
browser.td(:id, 'Proceed').element(:tag_name => 'FONT').class
```

returns watir::HTMLElement, but I cannot find any documentation for this (only Element)

using

```
browser.td(:id, 'Proceed').element(:tag_name => 'FONT').methods
```

shows that it has the method click, but running

```
browser.td(:id, 'Proceed').element(:tag_name => 'FONT').click
```

results in :

```
undefined method 'each' for "FONT":String (NoMethodError)
```

I have tried making a module for the font tag:

```
module Watir
    module Container
        def font(*args)
            FONT.new(self, extract_selector(args).merge(:tag_merge => "font"))
        end

        def fonts(*args)
            GCollection.new(self, extract_selector(args).merge(:tag_merge => "font"))
        end
    end

    class FONT < Element
    end

    class GCollection < ElementCollection
        def element_class
            FONT
        end
    end
end
```

but this throws the error,

```
undefined_method 'extract_selector' for #<Watir::TableRow:0x2835378> (NoMethodError)
```

How do I click on this unsupported tag?

Comment: Why are you limited to Watir-classic? Why not upgrade?

Comment: From watir.com, I believe I just did gem install watir --no-rdoc --no-ri -and that was the latest version. Is there a better version? ... and will it fix this?

Comment: See Justin's answer for a solution that should work for you. Also, I'd recommend looking into migrating to watir-webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running into [Issue 62](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/issues/62).

**Solution 1 - Upgrade Watir-Classic**

This bug is fixed in the latest version of watir-classic. Note that you need to upgrade the watir-classic gem (not just the watir gem):

```
gem install watir-classic
```

**Solution 2 - Use an Array**

If upgrading to the latest version is not an option, you can make the :tag_name value an array:

```
browser.td(:id, 'Proceed').element(:tag_name => ['FONT']).click
```

**Solution 3 - Use font method**

I just double-checked and the `font` element is actually [supported](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/supported_elements.rb#L99). So I would say the better solution, for this specific case at least, would be to use the `font` method:

```
browser.td(:id, 'Proceed').font.click
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I had been looking at https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir where font is not included - presumably this is out of date. I think another error must have tharted my original attempts which made me go there.